# Bayesian references

Tags: bayesian, bayes

Any good places to start getting into Bayesian statistics? I'm a graduate student in social sciences, with a decent amount of stats classes under my belt, but I'm far from fluent. Any references would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you, I am a graduate student in the social sciences and I have a decent amount of stats (and calculus) classes under my belt. I tried several books, and the one that wins it **BY FAR** is "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: A Tutorial with R and BUGS" by Kruschke (2010; [see on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123814855)).

The author, John Kruschke, also keeps an online blog about Bayesian statistics, that is a very nice companion to the book: http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/

The book gives plenty of code, and all programs are available on the author's website. The book also comes with a set of applied exercises at the end of each chapter, and the full solutions are again available on the author's website. Very warmly recommended.